# Lodash chaining?

Tags: javascript, json, lodash, chaining

I have a JSON object which looks like that:

```
{
      "ReceiptNumber": 2129,
      "ReceiptResult": 1,
      "ReceiptAmount": "6756",
      "ReceiptData": [
        {
          "LineNum": "JonSnow",
          "Data": "Standard data for Jon Snow"
        },
        {
          "LineNum": "HarryPotter",
          "Data": "Standard data for Harry Potter"
        },
        {
          "LineNum": "MickyMouse",
          "Data": "Standard data for Micky Mouse"
        }
      ],
      "ReceiptReference": "22e06e66-e711-bd14-7874a-002219649f24"
}
```

I'm trying to convert it into:

```
{
    "receiptNumber": 2129,
    "receiptResult": 1,
    "receiptAmount": "6756",
    "receiptData": {
        "jonSnow": "Standard data for Jon Snow",
        "harryPotter": "Standard data for Harry Potter",
        "mickyMouse": "Standard data for Micky Mouse"
    },
    "receiptReference": "22e06e66-e711-bd14-7874a-002219649f24"
}
```

The methods that I'm suing:

```
  getFromReceipt(result): void {
    result.ReceiptData = _.assign({}, ...result.ReceiptData.map(el => {
      return { [_.camelCase(el.LineNum)]: el.Data }
    }));

    this.camelCaseAllKeys(result);
  }

  camelCaseAllKeys(result) {
    return _.mapKeys(result, (v, k) => _.camelCase(k.toString()));
  }
```

Is there any way to simplify that methods and eventually do everything in one function through chaining?

Comment: *How fast is that?* o_O hold on I'll get my stop watch...If you want to know how fast it is, benchmark it

Comment: Note that you've got one function that does two distinct things: it mutates it's argument and then returns a modified copy of the mutated argument. That's generally not a good idea. Make it two functions and `compose` them.

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks for the advice, any example?

Comment: @Quang I can. Are you aware that for your `ReceiptData` your function repeatedly overwrites the `LineNum` and `Data` properties? Why not just `result.ReceiptData = result.ReceiptData[result.ReceiptData.length - 1]`? That would give the same result much faster.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm open to any solutions that will shorten the function and will be faster. Tried also with composition but that is not what I'm looking for sadly...

Comment: @Quang no I mean you are looping through `ReceiptData` like you need all of it but since you overwrite the properties with each object in the call to `Object.assign` it's as if you only grabbed the last object in the array. It's not clear what you are actually trying to accomplish here. Sample output would be welcome.

Comment: @JaredSmith Ok. I edited the question. Hope that this will highlight what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

You are conflating multiple concerns here in one function:

1. flatten the ReceiptData
2. camelcase the keys

It is not clear that those things should be in the same function: while it's shorter code that's a false economy. Once you run it through minifier + gzip the difference is negligible, and while shorter code is generally easier to read conflating different concerns makes it harder. Unless your dataset is truly massive (in which case why are you processing it client-side?) impact on runtime performance will be negligible.

So I would recommend something more like this:

```
let data = howeverYouGotTheData;
let flattenReceiptData = o => {
  o.ReceiptData = o.ReceiptData.reduce((acc, record) => {
    acc[_.camelCase(record.lineNum)] = record.Data;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return o;
};

let camelCaseKeys = o => {
  return Object.entries(o).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    acc[_.camelCase(k)] = v;
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

// _.flow is lodash's implementation of left composition
let flattenAndCase = _.flow(flattenReceiptData, camelCaseKeys);

let result = flattenAndCase(data);
```

Now the concerns are properly separated, everything is clearly named and easy to read, and so on. If you really want to golf this down you could use some standard tricks like this:

```
let cc = _.camelCase;
let flattenRD = o => (o.ReceiptData = o.ReceiptData.reduce((a, x) => (a[cc(x.lineNum)] = x.Data, a), {}));
```

etc. etc. I've used the comma operator to squish the assignment and return into one expression avoiding the need for `Object.assign`.